# throw new Error('data and salt arguments required'); - Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb

I have the following error saying data and salt arguments are required. Is it happening because of the password variable not matching? I don't understand fully. conpass and password is declared on html file as well in the formControlName and ids.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PrP8.png)

This is my users.js file

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
/* GET users listing. */
// router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.send('respond with a resource');
// });

router.post('/sign-in',function(req,res){
  addtoDB(req,res);
});

async function addtoDB(req,res){
  var user = new User({
    name:req.body.name,
    email:req.body.email,
    contact:req.body.contact,
    address:req.body.address,
    password:User.hashPassword(req.body.password),
    conpass:User.hashPassword(req.body.conpass), //confirm password
    creation_dt:Date.now()
  });

  try{
    doc=await user.save();
    return res.status(201).json(doc);
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    return res.status(501).json(err);
  }
}

module.exports = router;
```

And this is my app.js file

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var cors=require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors({
  origin:['http://localhost:4200','http://127.0.0.1:4200'],
  credentials:true
}));

var mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ElectroDB',{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Connection Successful!');
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

TS file

```js
import { NumberInput } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _router:Router, private fb: FormBuilder, private _userService:UserService) { }

  signUpForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [null, [Validators.required]],
    email: [null, [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
    contact: [null, [Validators.required]],
    address: [null, [Validators.required]],
    pass: [null, [Validators.required]],
    conpass: [null, [Validators.required]],
    // option: [null, [Validators.required]]
  });

  signInForm = this.fb.group({
    email: [null, [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
    pass: [null, [Validators.required]]
  });

  selected = new FormControl('valid', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('valid'),
  ]);

  selectFormControl = new FormControl('valid', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('valid'),
  ]);

  nativeSelectFormControl = new FormControl('valid', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('valid'),
  ]);

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  // favoriteSeason: string;
  // seasons: string[] = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'];
  // onLogin(form : NgForm)
  // {
  //   console.log(form.value)
  // }
  // onSingup(form : NgForm)
  // {
  //   console.log(form.value)
  // }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  signUp() {
    if (!this.signUpForm.valid || (this.signUpForm.controls.pass.value!=this.signUpForm.controls.conpass.value))
    {
      console.log("Invalid Form!")
      return;
    }
    this._userService.signin(JSON.stringify(this.signUpForm.value))
    .subscribe(
      data=>{
        console.log(data);
        this._router.navigate(['./home']);
      },
      error=>console.error(error)
    )
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.signUpForm.value))
  }

  signIn()
  {
    if (!this.signInForm.valid) {
      console.log("Invalid Form!")
      return;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.signInForm.value))
  }

}
```

Comment: please provide `'../models/user'` file

Comment: i think its related to User.hashPassword  function